# Find first occurrence from end of string

Tags: .net, regex

Is it possible to build a regular expression the locates the first occurrence of a pattern starting from the end of a string?

I want to find the first closing html tag that is preceded by at least 3 normal, not-html tag characters.

For example the following string contains a number of closing html tags.  I want to locate `ury.</` because that contains at least three non-html tag characters.

```
...to us the whole treasury.</span><br /><br /> </p></div>
```

Comment: What language is the regex used in?

Comment: Those are already four characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To locate the last occurrence of `</` with leading 3+ "non-tag" characters use regex pattern

```
[^<>]{3)<\/(?!.*[^<>]{3}<\/)
```

which uses a negative lookahead `(?!.*[^<>]{3}<\/)` to ensure there is not another occurrence ahead.

Comment: that really hurts my eyes. :)